# Powershell import multiple csv and group by name and total up wins

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import multiple `csv` files and output a total score, i don't want to create another `csv` for the output, below is how the `csv` is stored. below is `csv` 1

[image]

and this is `csv` 2

[image]

i want to group by Name and total the wins, please see code below that i have tried

```
get-item -Path "File Path"   | 
ForEach-Object {
import-csv $_| 
Group-Object Name
Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } } 
        }
```

i was hoping for an outcome like below

[image]

any help would be awesome

for some reason the current code is showing the below

[image]

Its looking better but still not grouping on Name

[image]

Comment: Didn't you forget the pipe symbol `|` at the end of line `Group-Object Name` ?

Comment: Thanks @Theo i have added the pipe and it has made it look better but still didnt group the Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the output you are expecting, with the names and total wins for each player.

```
$csv1 = import-csv "File path of CSV 1"
$csv2 = import-csv "File path of CSV 2"
$allRecords = $csv1 + $csv2
$allRecords | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
```

[image: csv files]

the ouptut
[image: output]

**Update**

*With multiple Csv Files*

```
$allRecords = @()
$directory = "Path of the directory containing the CSV files"
$filePaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter "*.csv"

foreach ($filePath in $filePaths) {
    $csv = import-csv $filePath
    $allRecords += $csv
}

$allRecords | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
```

Comment: What if he has 300 csv files? It;s nearly there, but this isnt the most efficient way to solve his problem.

Comment: @Mohammed Chaaraoui thank you for your answer but i have quite a few csv files

Comment: you can use a loop to iterate over each file and import its contents, then combine all the records into a single variable. i will update my answer to solve this

Comment: Why not just "$allRecords += Import-Csv $filePath" ? :)

Comment: Bear in mind that using `+=` is very slow and there are better methods if you have thousands of csv files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very high number of csv files, you'll find something like this much faster:

```
$CombinedRecords = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Path C:\temp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv 
$CombinedRecords | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
```

It can even be a one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Path C:\temp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name, @{ n='Wins'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Wins -Sum).Sum } }
```

Comment: thank you for your help @Scepticalist , i will also try this